# Google Assistant, custom command with a custom response

Tags: google-home, esp32, home-assistant

I'm looking for a way to reply on a custom command with a custom text in Google Assistant.
E.g. "Hey Google, what's the temperature in my Living Room?" - "In your living Room you have 22°C"

## Solution's I tried so far:

#### Dialogflow/Actions SDK:

- The Problem with this Solution is, that I either need to use the Prefix : "*Hey Google Ask Temperature App*, what's the temperature in my Living Room" or with Deep Link I need to answer a second question:
  "Hey Google what's the temp",
  "Do You want to use the Temperature App to answer this question?"
  "Yes"
  "Starting the Test version of Temperature App. The Temperature is ...."
- The second Problem is that Google always answers the commands with "I'm launching the test version of Temperature App". To Remove this annoying monolog I need to deploy the App. However I don't want that everyone has access to the temperature of my Rooms.

#### IFTTT + esp8266-google-home-notifier

- IFTTT supports custom commands, but the custom answer with esp8266-google-home-notifier can only be sent to one specific device.

#### Tasker's AutoVoice

- Same Problem as the Actions SDK. "Ask AutoVoice to, `<custom command>`"

Has anyone any idea what I could try next?
And yes, I know alexa (and even siri) can do this without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Node-RED](https://nodered.org/) and the [Node-RED Google Assistant Bridge](https://googlehome.hardill.me.uk/)

Sensor Example discussed [here](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2021/03/12/google-assistant-sensors/)

You will need something like a Raspberry Pi to run Node-RED, and sensors that can be queried from Node-RED, so ESP8266 sensors with either HTTP or MQTT would work well.

Full disclosure, I wrote/run the Node-RED Google Assistant Bridge.